# Overriding QPushButton Class Event Method with PySide

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside

I am wanting to make a custom button class that allows for **clicking** and **drag and drop**. I also want the ability to control the aesthetics of it (button color, mouse over color, clicked color, drag over color, etc.).

***Note: these examples are shorter, generic versions of what I need to do. I know it doesn't contain all necessary things to work and some names of variables and functions are just examples. My real example will need as many as 15 instances of this class instead of the 4 shown.***

In the example of **clicking** the button, as soon as I override the **mousePressEvent** and the **mouseReleaseEvent** the `my_button.clicked.connect(my_func)` statement no longer works. And being that I want to use this custom class for all kinds of button functions I can't just put the button functions in the overridden method, which is what my current solution is and I hate it (see below). I tried using the `super(DropZone_Category, self)mouseReleaseEvent(event)` statement after my style sheet changes (as suggested in other questions) but this did absolutely nothing for me. All I really wanted to do with these overrides was control the style sheet so if there is a better way to do this, please advise.

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore


class DropZone_Category(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DropZone_Category, self).__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        # Instance Attrs
        self.parent = parent

        # Style Variables
        self.dropZone_font = QtGui.QFont()
        self.dropZone_font.setPointSize(16)
        self.dropZone_font.setFamily("Calibri")
        self.default_button_stylesheet = "background-color: rgb(100,100,100);" \
                                         "color: lightgrey;" \
                                         "border-radius: 3px;"

        self.drag_button_stylesheet = "background-color: rgb(166,215,176);" \
                                          "color: rgb(0,97,19);" \
                                          "border-radius: 3px;"

        self.hover_button_stylesheet =  "background-color: rgb(150,150,150);" \
                                         "color: lightgrey;" \
                                         "border-radius: 3px;"

        self.clicked_button_stylesheet = "background-color: rgb(80,80,80);" \
                                         "color: lightgrey;" \
                                         "border-radius: 3px;"

        # Overrides
        self.resize(QtCore.QSize(120, 120))
        self.setFont(self.dropZone_font)
        self.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.setMinimumSize(90, 90)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setStyleSheet(self.default_button_stylesheet)

    def enterEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.setStyleSheet(self.hover_button_stylesheet)

    def leaveEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.setStyleSheet(self.default_button_stylesheet)

    def mousePressEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.setStyleSheet(self.clicked_button_stylesheet)
        # super(DropZone_Category, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event,*args, **kwargs):
        button_used = self.text()
        self.setStyleSheet(self.default_button_stylesheet)
        # super(DropZone_Category, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

        if button_used == "btn1":
            btn1_clicked_func()
        elif button_used == "btn2":
            btn2_clicked_func()
        elif button_used == "btn3":
            btn3_clicked_func()
        elif button_used == "btn4":
            btn4_clicked_func()
```

In the example of the **drag and drop** functionality, I need an easier, cleaner way of setting up the drop function for each button, as it is different for each instance needed. Something similar to the `my_button.clicked.connect(my_func)` if possible. If not possible I'm open to other suggestions. I am currently handling it like the mouseReleaseEvent method above but in the **dropEvent** method, which I again...hate.

```
def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            self.setStyleSheet(self.drag_button_stylesheet)

            event.acceptProposedAction()
        else:
            super(DropZone_Category, self).dragEnterEvent(event)

def dragLeaveEvent(self, event):
    self.setStyleSheet(self.default_button_stylesheet)

def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
    super(DropZone_Category, self).dragMoveEvent(event)

def dropEvent(self, event):
    zone_used = self.text()
    paths_list = [url.toLocalFile() for url in event.mimeData().urls()]
    num_files = len(paths_list)

    if not utils.isImages(paths_list): # check if drop objects are images
        print "Drop Rejected: Not all files dropped were images"
    elif not event.mimeData().hasUrls(): # check if drop objects are files
        print "Drop Rejected: Not all items dropped were files"
    else:
        if button_used == "btn1":
            btn1_dropped_func(paths_list )
        elif button_used == "btn2":
            btn2_dropped_func(paths_list )
        elif button_used == "btn3":
            btn3_dropped_func(paths_list )
        elif button_used == "btn4":
            btn4_dropped_func(paths_list )


        sleep(.5)
        self.setStyleSheet(self.default_button_stylesheet)
```

As said above, the main reason for this mess is that that I really want to learn how to control the aesthetics of a UI. That coupled with the large number of very specific instances that will be used from these classes and the added drag and drop functionality has turned this into a headache for me. My current conclusion (with others advice) is to create a sub class of this base class for each special instance I need (ie 15 subclasses of DropZone_Categories). I would really hate to do this because it feels like it violates the entire reason for making classes. If this is the only solution I will happily do it but I just wanted to see before making even more of a mess. Thanks and SORRY for for the long post.

Comment: Why do you say you need 15 subclasses? After a lot of text and your long and sad story, which after all bores us, you have not indicated why you have to do 15 classes.

Comment: Because the dropEvent for each instance of the buttons are vastly different from the rest in most cases. Enough so that abstraction isn't an option. Some need to rename one dropped file to a specific name. Others need to take multiple files and check for strings in their names and then decide how to rename each file and the parameters for those are different based on the instance that the files are dropped on. All that and I don't want a drop function that is 500 lines long. I just want to be able to connect a function to a dropEvent like you would to a button click...

Comment: For me to explain to you the exact functionality of this program and why I need it to work like this would take so much longer than the 3 minutes of reading above. Which is why I cut it down to a generic example to represent my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see first of all that you are using the Qt StyleSheet incorrectly, the QSS handle pseudo-states like `hover` and `pressed`, so it is not necessary to change the QSS at every moment besides that task is expensive.

The solution in that case is to use the pseudo-states:

```
DropZone_Category{
    background-color: rgb(100,100,100);
    color: lightgrey;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

DropZone_Category:hover{
    background-color: rgb(150,150,150);
    color: lightgrey;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

DropZone_Category:pressed{
    background-color: rgb(80,80,80);
    color: lightgrey;
    border-radius: 3px
}
```

According to what you mention, which was the most relevant information regarding your post, you want each button to process the files differently, so the best option is to create a signal that sends the files to the slot that will be responsible for processing it. In the following example, 4 buttons have been created where each one can be connected to a slot that the files obtain, then it is your responsibility the part of the logic that processes those files.

```
import sys

from PySide import QtGui, QtCore


class DropZone_Category(QtGui.QPushButton):
    pathsChanged = QtCore.Signal(list)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DropZone_Category, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        font = self.font()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        self.setFont(font)
        self.resize(QtCore.QSize(120, 120))
        self.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.setMinimumSize(90, 90)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        QSS = """
            DropZone_Category{
                background-color: rgb(100,100,100);
                color: lightgrey;
                border-radius: 3px;
            }

            DropZone_Category:hover{
                background-color: rgb(150,150,150);
                color: lightgrey;
                border-radius: 3px;
            }

            DropZone_Category:pressed{
                background-color: rgb(80,80,80);
                color: lightgrey;
                border-radius: 3px
            }
        """
        self.setStyleSheet(QSS)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        paths_list = [url.toLocalFile() for url in event.mimeData().urls()]
        if paths_list:
            self.pathsChanged.emit(paths_list)

class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        info = [("category 1", self.fun1), ("category 2", self.fun2), ("category 3", self.fun3), ("category 4", self.fun4)]

        for text, fun in info:
            button = DropZone_Category(text)
            button.pathsChanged.connect(fun)
            lay.addWidget(button)

    def fun1(self, files):
        print("fun1", files)

    def fun2(self, files):
        print("fun2", files)

    def fun3(self, files):
        print("fun3", files)

    def fun4(self, files):
        print("fun4", files)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! This is exactly what I needed. I have had such a hard time understanding how to use signals and slots and this makes it so clear. Only two things I'm still fuzzy on...where is "list" coming from in the pathsChanged = QtCore.Signal(list) statement? And where can I find a reference of all of the pseudo states? Are there others besides hover and pressed, like dragOver or something similar?

Comment: @Huston94 A signal carries some information, in the example it declares the signal: `pathsChanged = QtCore.Signal(list)`, as you see the argument that happened to it was the type of data, in this case it indicates that I am going to send a `list`, After emited the signal: `self.pathsChanged.emit(paths_list)` send the list `path_list`, it will pass it to the slot associated with it.

Comment: @Huston94 see http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html, http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Sorry if I seemed hard to get proper info from. I just wasn't sure how to go about explain the desired output logic for all 15 instances in a short comment. Main main issue was the PySide culture stuff like this anyways. Many, Many thanks!

Comment: @Huston94 I recommend you to understand how Qt handles signals and events, for it reads http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html , http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

Comment: I agree. I've wanted to learn more about it recently and it never really showed it self that much until I started this project. Up until now I have done very basic UI design. I will definitely be reading through this.